# dplyr Replace values in multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, magrittr

I need to replace non-4 with 80 in cyl, gear, carb columns. I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear, carb), replace(which(.!=4), 80))
```

It throws the following error:

```
Error in replace(which(. != 4), 80) : 
  argument "values" is missing, with no default
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a function or formula to `mutate_at` as second argument:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear, carb), ~ replace(., which(.!=4), 80))
```

Or create the function using `funs`:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear, carb), funs(replace(., which(.!=4), 80)))
```

Comment: Got it. Fantastic! Thanks!